# How to code fold parenthesis () in R / RShiny App using RStudio hot key?

Tags: r, code-folding

I use code folding + the code folding hot key all the time in R to keep my scripts organized. If everything is in functions and the functions do the work, the folded code is very neat.

How can we code fold the `dashboardBody()` call below? If I add `#####` between lines 32 & 33, the entire script below line 33 folds into one fold which is problematic, as I just want the dashboardBody() function to fold into itself here.

[image]

I tried this where I wrapped the whole thing in curly braces

```
ui_body <- {dashboardBody(

  # Shiny HTML Tags 
  tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css_fixed_sidebar))),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css_dashboard_body_white))),
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css_nyk_grey_header))),
  
  # UI Body for this page
  tabItems(
    create_ui__glossary(id = NA) # NA for no server module
  )
)}
```

...and while the code-folding icon does appear here

[image]

...it is problematic because (a) it would be better if `dashboardBody()` still showed, like how the function names show when they are collapsed (although this may not be possible), and more importantly (b) the RStudio code-folding hot key (ALT-O on Windows) for some reason doesn't work to fold this section for some reason, and so I have to manually click the arrow to fold this code, which defeats the purpose of using the hot-key to code-fold entire scripts.

Is there another approach?

Comment: Long story short: I don’t think you can. I caution against over-reliance on code folding — I feel that it’s an unnecessary crutch and I don’t think it’s useful in cleanly written code. But I fully accept the possibility that I’m wrong on this.

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps I can just wrap the whole thing in a function that returns the `dashboardBody()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a function and fold the function...

```
create_ui_body <- function() {
  return (
    dashboardBody(
       ...
    )
  )
}
ui_body <- create_ui_body()
```

Folds into this:

[image]

I'd be interested to hear if anybody can point to any issues with this approach.